# Add up all elements of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a very specific problem and I have no idea how to solve it. Im really new to python, so I would love to get a helping hand. Basically I need to add up all elements (ints) in a list together, but not using sum(). Like this:

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

What I need is that its adds up value of [0]+[1],[0]+[2] etc.
then it does [1]+[2], [1]+[3] etc.
But then it does it all again with three numbers, then four etc.

It is really hard to explain, hope you can understand it, if not just tell me I will try to explain it a bit better.

Comment: traverse through list and add each number and save result in another variable

Comment: What you should do with the calculated values (e.g. print it to the screen or save it into a list)?

Comment: Sounds like you need `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: Did you write any code yourself? If so edit it into the question as a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started.  It does all combinations of 2 numbers, then 3, then 4, etc:

```
import itertools

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for cbos in range(2,len(my_list)):
    sums = list(sum(s) for s in itertools.combinations(my_list,cbos))
    print( f"Combinations of {cbos}: {sums}" )
```

Output:

```
Combinations of 2: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11]
Combinations of 3: [6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15]
Combinations of 4: [10, 11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 13, 14, 15, 16, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
Combinations of 5: [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```